# Conditionals operation helps in php

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hello everybody i put this code but and when the value referal is < 0 running }else{ but i dont do.

```
if($referal > 0 && is_numeric($referal) && $site['refsys'] == 1 && $site['aff_click_req'] == 0){
                //code

                if($user['id'] > 0){
                    //code
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to put }else{ but not how, }else{ $referal="$referal2"; ????

```
if($referal > 0 && is_numeric($referal) && $site['refsys'] == 1 && $site['aff_click_req'] == 0){
                //code

                if($user['id'] > 0){
                    //code
                }
            }}else{ $referal="$referal2";
        }
```

Regards and thanks

Comment: use `else` and wrap it in Parens `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this the if elseif statement syntax.

```
if($condition1){
    // code if the first condition is true
}elseif($condition2){
    // code if the first condition is false and the second one is true
}else{
    // code if both the first and second condition are false
}
```

it is described in [the php official website](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

If I have understood your question you want, when the `$referal1` is equal to 0, to set the value of `$referal2` to `$referal1`.
In this case your code should be something like this

```
if($referal > 0 && is_numeric($referal) && $site['refsys'] == 1 && $site['aff_click_req'] == 0){
    //code

    if($user['id'] > 0){
        //code
    }
}elseif($referal==0){
    $referal=$referal2;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Exactyyyy was that!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you so much took hours looking for that could be, I am newbie, thank you, you saved me !!